# Всплывающее уведомление в Telegram Bot

Tags: php, api, telegram-bot

Видел такую штуку у многих ботов. Кто знает как реализовать, желательно показать на примере правильного запроса к API. Я вывожу кнопки через `inline_keyboard` и хочу при удачном или неудачном запросе, выводить данное уведомление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть спец метод для нотификации https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery

Пример зависит от того на каком ЯП ты реализуеш функционал. 
В общем и целом запрос к API выглядит так:

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<ID>/answerCallbackQuery?callback_query_id=<query_id>&text=<text>&show_alert=1&cache_time=0`

Comment: уже сам разобрался, в принципе тоже самое и сделал и заработало.